# How do I get `overflow-x` to work on multiple contained floated div?

Tags: html, css

How can I get a `div` with `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow: auto;` to scroll multiple contained `div`s?

If I have a single `div`, with a single child `div`, and the child `div` is wider than the container, then `overflow:scroll;` works great.

```css
div.container {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    div.inner2 {
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="inner2">
        ABCD1234WXYZ ABCD1234WXYZ 
      </div>
    </div>
```

But if I have multiple inner floated `div`s, where each one is **less** than the width of the container, but in sum they are **greater** than the container, it wraps the floated `div`s.

```css
 div.inner {
        width: 100px;
        float: left;
    }
    div.container {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    div.container:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">ABCD</div>
        <div class="inner">1234</div>
        <div class="inner">WXYZ</div>
    </div>
```

How do I get it to append the floating `div`s horizontally and scroll?

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hw4ykza6/

Note that the contained `div`s will be resized at various times. I do not know in advance what the max or min width for them will be, only what they are now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i've achieved what you want here (note i only applied my changes to your top example):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hw4ykza6/4/)

The key things to note are:

1. I've added an inner wrapping element with `class="inner-container"` that is `display:table-row`
2. The elements of class `inner` now have `display:table-cell`

Comment: So I like it, but the issue is that I don't know in advance what the height will be. That needs to be dynamic as well.

Comment: @deitch not saying its necessary, but is javascript an option?

Comment: Sure is. Actually, there are separators between the `div`s (just narrow `div`s) that the user drags to resize... hence all the headache.

Comment: Oh, I think I got something.

Comment: @deitch see my updated fiddle above^  .Turns out I didnt need all those absolute positioned things if I go further down the table display rabbit hole.

Comment: That table display rabbit hole is not bad. But I could not replicate it!

Comment: @deitch did you remove the `float:left` from the inner class wherever youre trying to replicate it at?

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Use the `display` without the floats. Fantastic.

Comment: Almost, but not quite. When I set it to `table-cell`, `div.inner` shrinks to the text size, i.e. it ignores `width:100px;`. How do I have it have the fixed width?

Comment: Ah, yes, need to set `min-width`. Of course, then you cannot have overflow inside the `div`s hidden...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need floats there. `div.inner {display: table-cell;}` will give you what you want:

```css
 div.inner {
        width: 100px;
        display: table-cell;
    }
    div.container {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">ABCD</div>
        <div class="inner">1234</div>
        <div class="inner">WXYZ</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are right, thank you. But @rooster had it above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a **dispaly: inline-block;** style and apply that style to all the child divs
e.g

```
<div style="width:300px; overflow-x:scroll; height:auto;">
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:200px; display:inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:200px; display:inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:200px; display:inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:200px; display:inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:200px; display:inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:200px; display:inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:200px; display:inline-block;">
  </div>
</div>
```

***Note:am using inline styling for explanatory purposes***
You could try coding with less so you can get your heights as a single variable so u can then use later

Comment: m sorry please i dnt get wat u want 2 achieve, just looked at the jsfiddle and it looks 2 me like you have achieved wat you want to do